# import module.fucntion working but import { function } from '../../module' not working in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

Having some import issues, basically if I do something like:

```
import module from '../../module'
console.log(module.func)
```

This prints out the function which is expected behaviour however if I do this:

```
import { func } from '../../module'
console.log(func)
```

It prints out undefined.

I'm not exactly using it this way but am calling the function. However using the second import method, I get a `uncaught TypeError: object(...) is not a function`

Things to note: "func" is located in index.jsx of folder "module" along with some other functions so I can't use import * . It has also been exported.

I'm not sure why React is unable to find the functions inside the file using the second method, any help/explanation at all would be appreciated.

Edit:
This is how I'm exporting the function:

```
const func = (param, param) => {
....
return result
};

const func1 = (param, param) => {...}
.
.
.
export default{
func,
func1,
func2,
...
};
```

Comment: How exactly are you exporting the func in module page? If you're doing it like this `export const func...`, then importing `import { func } from '../../module'` should work

Comment: @mindmaster Updated the description with it

Comment: In js, when you export something as default, you import it just by a name (as in import Default thing from ...). You currently are exporting an object (the object with func, func1, etc) as the default and so, if you want to access it, you need to import the default (which is the object) and get it by key. You should probably ditch the default and export every function as export const funcName; That way you can import the way you want to. Perhaps you are confusing import DefaultName from ...; with import * as some name from ...; This way, with the non-dedault exports, it works as you want.

Comment: ah! that solved my confusion thanks @asharpharp 
I can't accept comments as answers, if you post it as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're exporting the function not the way you're supposed to. Your function should look something like this:

```
export const func = () => {
  // Code.
};
```

Importing it would look like this:

```
import { func } from '[path]'
```